# gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image boot: display on USB disk booting Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

Please anybody can solve this bug

**gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image boot:**

display on bootable USB disk Ubuntu 15.04 installing with USB disk after creating properly on Ubuntu 14.04 '*Startup Disk Creator*'.

Comment: Which architecture is the ISO for (i386 or amd64) and which CPU do you have?

Comment: Having exactly the same problem here. For the answer of @KarlRichter 's comment - I have iso for i386 architecture  .